# How to find the intensity function of the non-homogeneous poisson porcess

Tags: probability

I was just wondering how to find the intensity function of the non-homogeneous poisson process if the uniformly distributed arrival times is replaced with beta distribution.

What I am thinking about is to figure out the mean value function m(t), i.e. the expected number of the points simulated from the beta distribution then use the relationship between m(t) and the intensity function to get the intensity function by differentiating m(t).

Question:
How to find the mean value function in this case? Thanks a lot!